# How to read Form data from Execution listener

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

I'm working with `activiti-5.21.0`. i have 
i have created `myProcess.bpmn`, that have user task. user task have a form. When this form will be submitted by assignee user i.e. "kermit" then How to read data submitted in form in java class?

`myProcess.bpmn` model:

```
  <process id="myProcess" name="My process" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="usertask1" name="User Task" activiti:assignee="kermit">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:formProperty id="name" name="Name" type="string" required="true"></activiti:formProperty>
        <activiti:formProperty id="comment" name="comment" type="string"></activiti:formProperty>
        <activiti:executionListener event="start" class="com.demo.ActivitiForm"></activiti:executionListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="usertask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="usertask1" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Execution `event="end"` then try this -

```
package com.demo;

//all import statement

public class ActivitiForm implements ExecutionListener {

  public void notify(ExecutionListenerExecution execution) throws Exception {
    String name = (String) execution.getVariable("name");
    String comment = (String) execution.getVariable("comment");
    System.out.println(name + " made the following comment: " + comment);           //see this sys.out in your admin log.
  }
}
```

Comment: i also make event="end", for reading data after submitt.  <activiti:executionListener event="end" class="com.demo.ActivitiForm"></activiti:executionListener>

Answer (score 1):

if you want to access variable from anywhere (irrespective of flow). using process instance id, you can try this -

```
Map<String, Object> variables = runtimeService.getVariables(processInstanceId);
String name = (String)variable.get("name");
String comment = (String)variable.get("comment");
```